# Question about Chebyshev Inequality ,how to show $\lim_{a\to\infty}a^2P(|X|\geq a)/E(X^2)=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose $X$ is a random variable such that $0<E(X^2)<\infty$, show that
>
> $$\lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{a^2P(|X|\geq a)}{E(X^2)} = 0$$

Solution:

It seems that

$$\lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{a^2\int I(|X(w)|\geq a) \ P(dw)}{\int |X(w)|^2 \, P(dw)}
= \frac{\int \lim_{a\to\infty} a^2 I(|X(w)|\geq a) \, P(dw)}{\int |X(w)|^2 \, P(dw)} = 0$$

According to Dominated Convergence Theorem. Since $a^2 I(|X|\geq a)$ is less than $ X^2$.

Though I am not clear on the step :  How to show $a^2 I(|X|\geq a)\rightarrow 0 $ a.s. Can any one give some hint?  I am a self learner and I have just started to learn something about measure theory and advanced probability.

Comment: First of all, why can you apply the bounded convergence theorem? Mind you that $a^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{ |X| \geq a\}}$ is not bounded in general. Also, it is not clear what it means by $\int |X|^2 \, \mathrm{d}u$. You may either write $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|X(\omega)|^2\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega)$ (i.e., integration with respect to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$) or $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}F_X(x)$ (as in LOTUS).

Comment: It is dominated  convergence theorem. I will make some change. $a^2 P(|X|\geq a)=a^2 E(I(|X|\geq a))$, Here $a^2(I(|X|\geq a))$ is less or equal to $a^2 X^2$

Comment: I think you mean $a^2 I(|X| \geq a) \leq X^2$. Then, together with justt's answer, you can apply Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude that the limit is zero. ($E(X^2)$ in the denominator really plays no role in this discussion.)

Comment: I will make some change soon. The system limit my times to make some change.  So I need to wait. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added the proof of the domination to my answer. Note that you were talking at some point about dominating by $a^2X^2$. This wouldn't work. The theorem does not work if the domination depends on $a$.

Comment: @SangchulLee and justt, Thanks for all your nice explanation and wonderful help. To  Theoretical Economist , Thanks for your nice question.

Comment: @ justt,  Get it. It is an indicator function, which are either 0 or 1. Also the dominated function should not be affected by the limitation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As soon as $a>|X|$, $a^2I(|X|\geq a) = 0$. In particular since $|X|$ is a finite number almost surely, then almost surely, $a^2I(|X|\geq a)$ is eventually $0$ as $a\to\infty$, which is the most brutal way of converging to zero.

EDIT: to show the domination 
$$a^2I(|X|\geq a) \leq |X|^2$$
there are two cases. Either $|X|<a$, and the indicator is zero, and the equality becomes $0\leq |X|^2$, which is obviously true. Either $|X|\geq a$, and the indicator is one, and the equality becomes $a^2\leq |X|^2$, which is true in this case.

Comment: To Justt,Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\mathsf{E}X^2\ge a^2\mathsf{P}(|X|\ge a)+\mathsf{E}[X^21\{|X|<a\}],
$$
for any sequence $a_n\nearrow \infty$ one gets (using Fatou's lemma)
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n^2\mathsf{P}(|X|\ge a_n)&\le \mathsf{E}X^2-\liminf_{n\to \infty}\mathsf{E}[X^2 1\{|X|<a_n\}] \\
&\le \mathsf{E}X^2-\mathsf{E}\!\left[\liminf_{n\to\infty}X^21\{|X|<a_n\}\right]=0.
\end{align}

Comment: @d.k.o.Thanks for your explain in details. It gives  me a new way to understand it.